# REST Endpoint from non-entity object

Tags: rest, spring-boot

New to Spring - I want to have a REST endpoint that exposes results from a SQL query. The Amount class is not `@Entity`, but some fields from another table. I could declare it as an `@Entity`, but then Spring Data will create a table for Amount, which I do not want. However without `@Entity`, Spring will complain:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface com.swed.fuelcounter.entities.Amount
```

The code below works fine for me, but I don't need an Amount Entity, how can I do without it?

Service class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
class AmountsService {
    private final AmountRepository repository;

    public AmountsService(AmountRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/amount-by-month", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<AmountInterface>> getAmountByMonth(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        List<Amount> amounts = repository.sumAmountByDateAndDriver(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(amounts, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Amount POJO class:

```
public class Amount {

    public Amount(double amount, Date date){
        this.amount = amount;
        this.date = date;
    }


    @Getter
    @Setter
    private double amount;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Date date;
}
```

Repository interface and RepositoryImpl class:

```
public interface AmountRepository extends JpaRepository<Amount, Long> {

    List<Amount> sumAmountByDateAndDriver(int id);
}

@Component
public class AmountRepositoryImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private AmountRepository repository;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public List<Amount> sumAmountByDateAndDriver(int id) {
        String hql = "SELECT NEW Amount(Sum(price*volume) as amount, date) FROM record WHERE id = :id GROUP BY date";
        TypedQuery<Amount> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Amount.class);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Comment: If Amount is not a JPA entity, you can't use Spring Data JPA interfaces for it (i.e. you can't extend JpaRepository). Also, you probably want your Impl class to implement the interface, no? Because with your current code, your Impl class is used nowhere.

Comment: Impl class is used by Spring to run the methods. If I shouldn't use JPA, can you hint what I should use?

Comment: Where do you use it? AmountRepositoryImpl doesn't implement AmountRepository, so it will not be injected in AmountsService

Comment: I am not a Spring expert by any means, but I understand the @Component annotation should do the injection, and it does in my code. Anyway, I found a solution - JPA Projection

Answer (score 0):

In my case we make the Entity as Immutable as shown below. Hence store the database results in the Amount Object.

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Getter
public class Amount {

   public Amount(double amount, Date date){
      this.amount = amount;
      this.date = date;
   }

   /* The No-Args Constructor is needed for Hibernate */
   public Amount() { }

   @Column
   private double amount;

   @Column
   private Date date;
}
```